# What should I do about a job offer which I haven't noticed on time?

Tags: new-hires

About one year ago I bought a VPS and changed my email address. I forgot to change my LinkedIn email address. I normally don't check LinkedIn when I don't receive an email. Recently I had to check something on my old email address, and I saw that I had many, many emails from LinkedIn for endorsements. So I logged in at LinkedIn and I saw I had about 3 or 4 job offers which I didn't notice on time (I think that they were sent about 3 months before I saw them).

What should I do about this? Should I reply and apologize for the late reaction, though they may already have hired somebody? Or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's done is done. You can contact the senders, tell them that you missed their communication, that the positions that they mentioned caught your interest now that you are reading about them, and that you are looking forward to getting new communications about new open positions from them.